# C# with ServiceStack and Angular - Use enumeration classes instead of enum types in dto.ts

Tags: c#, servicestack

How can I get access to the properties (ex. `AddressChanges`) of my custom enum-class in the `dto.ts` file generated by ServiceStack for Angular?

**Enum with base-class**

```
public class MutationType : Enumeration
{
    public static MutationType AddressChanges = new MutationType(1, nameof(AddressChanges));
    public static MutationType SomethingElse = new MutationType(2, nameof(SomethingElse));
    ...

    public MutationType(int id, string name)
        : base(id, name)
    {
    }
}
```

**Auto generated dto.ts with Service-Stack**

```
export class MutationType extends Enumeration
{
    // The static fields are missing..
    public constructor(init?: Partial<MutationType>) { super(init); (Object as any).assign(this, init); }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, a DTO (Data Transfer Object) should not have any logic or implementation. Only the data structure (i.e. Schema) of the DTO is able to be converted with [ServiceStack's Native Types generation](https://docs.servicestack.net/add-servicestack-reference) feature.

So your [DTO Service Models](https://docs.servicestack.net/service-complexity-and-dto-roles#data-transfer-objects---dtos) should only contain implementation-free data structures, like enums:

```
public enum MutationType
{
    AddressChanges,
    SomethingElse,
}
```

Or if you prefer to send enum values as integers you can annotate them with the `[Flags]` attribute:

```
[Flags]
public enum MutationType
{
    AddressChanges = 1,
    SomethingElse = 2,
}
```

Where you would then need to map the value from the enum back into your custom complex Enumeration type, but all Service Models going in or out of your Service Layer should just be POCO DTOs.